# Downloading progress in AsyncTask android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create downloading progress. I have my class which extends AsyncTask:
**public class DownloadFileTask extends AsyncTask**

When downloading starts i want to create progress:

```
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {



   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(whatContext);
   progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
   progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
   progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
   progressDialog.show();
  }
```

But i don't know what context i should give to  new ProgressDialog becouse i am not in Activity class. I tried to give some context but there an error:

**No enclosing instance of the type Main_Tab is accessible in 
 scope**

So how i could create this progress ?

Also i wanted to create progress not in this class (becouse i want seperate functions and design), but i did't figure out how to do that.

Thank you guys for help.

Comment: "i am not in Activity class." - Why not? The main use of an `AsyncTask` is to allow asynchronous processing that doesn't hold up an `Activity`. If you're creating an `AsyncTask` in some other way then perhaps you need to rethink what it is you need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 public class DownloadFileTask extends AsyncTask{
Context mContext;

    public DownloadFileTask(Context context) {
            this.mContext = context;

        }


     @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {



       progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
       progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
       progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
       progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
       progressDialog.show();
      }
    }
```

To start DownloadTask call like

```
 DownloadFileTask task = new DownloadFileTask(MyActivity.This);
 task.execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a constructor for your `AsyncTask`, that takes a `Context` object as a parameter, for example:

```
public DownloadFileTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

Then you can use the `context` field to initialize the `ProgressDialog`. Concerning the second question - there is not enough info to answer it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess passing the context to your customized AsyncTask Loaders's constructor can do the trick.